# Открытие Alertdialog по нажатию элемента RecyclerView(CardView)

Tags: java, android

Необходимо по нажатию на элемент, открыть AlertDialog и передать в него объект.
Не видео метод getLayoutInflater

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView tvShopName;
        public TextView tvChainStores;
        public TextView tvShopAddress;
        public TextView tvShopModeWork;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvShopName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewShopName);
            tvChainStores = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChainStores);
            tvShopAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewShopAddress);
            tvShopModeWork = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewShopModeWork);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Shop shop = shops.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
                    builder.setTitle("Выберите действие");

                    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog_select_action_shop, null);
                    builder.setView(dialogView);

                    Button btnPointMap = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonPointShop);

                    Button btnCancel = (Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
//                  Button btnSuccess = (Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnSuccess);

                    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

                    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Вы не выбрали действие", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    btnPointMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {




                        }
                    });


                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: лучше использовать `LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(...)` и передавать/находить в адаптере контекст. А вообще - правильно все делать в DialogFragment (и выносить логику диалога из адаптера)